# Getting the progress of the sent data through Zend Rest service

Tags: zend-framework, rest, service, frameworks

I have the following situation. We are using **Zend Framework** to create a web application that is communicating with it's database through **REST services**.
The problem I'm facing is that when a user tries to upload a **big video file** for example, the service is taking some time (sometimes a few minutes) to receive the request (which is also sending the video file encoded with **base64_encode** PHP function.) and returns the response for successful save or error.

My idea is to track how much of the data is sent and show the user a JS progress bar, which will be useful in these cases. 
Does anyone have an idea, how I can track how much of the data is sent through the service and based on this I'll be able to show a progress bar?

Answer (score 0):

Zend provides progress bar functionalities that might be paired with some javascript/jquery client.

You will easily find some example implementations like this one:

https://github.com/marcinwol/zfupload

However I don't think that REST services are the best solution for uploading videos as base64 encoding will make files bigger and slower to upload.

Check out **Zend_File_Transfer** that might be better suited to your needs:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.file.transfer.introduction.html